A variant of Schwarz's theorem on generators of smooth $G$-invariant functions
Let $V$ be a finite dimensional euclidean space and let $G\subset O(V)$ be a finite (or compact) group, let $\mathbb{R}[V]$ be the algebra of polynomial functions on $V$. If $E\subset \mathcal{C}^\infty(V)$ is a sub algebra, we denote by $E^G$ the sub-algebra of $G$-invariant function of $E$.
A theorem of Schwarz says:
Theorem : Let $(P_1,\dotsc,P_k)$ be a system of generators of $\mathbb{R}[V]^G$ as an algebra over $\mathbb{R}$, then $\mathcal{C}^\infty(V)^G$ is "smoothly generated" by $(P_1,\dotsc,P_k)$ in the sense that the map:
$$\begin{align}\mathcal{C}^\infty(\mathbb{R}^k)&\to \mathcal{C}^\infty(V)^G\\\\ g&\mapsto g(P_1,\dots,P_k)
\end{align}$$
is surjective (and continuous in the right topologies).
There is also another proof by Bierstone in case $G$ is finite (although the proof only works at the level of germs of smooth functions if I understand correctly).
My question relates to the extension of this kind of results to subalgebras of smooth functions.

Question
Let $E\subset \mathcal{C}^\infty(V)$ be such that $(E\cap \mathbb{R}[V])^G$ is generated as an algebra over $\mathbb{R}$ by $(Q_1,\dots,Q_k)$, under what conditions on $E$ and $G$ is $E^G$
"smoothly generated" by $(Q_1,\dotsc,Q_k)$ ?

I'm currently trying to read through the proofs of Schwarz and Bierstone but have yet to understand if and how they can be adapted to this setting. The case of a finite group $G$ is already very interesting for what I have in mind. If this helps, one can also assume that $E$ is actually an ideal.
An obvious restriction should be that $E$ and $E^G$ contain enough polynomials, and probably density of $\mathbb{R}[V]\cap E$ in $E$ at least for the $\mathcal{C}_\text{loc}^0$ topology should be required.
Additional remark :
I'm realising that there is a perhaps more general question lurking around which has nothing to do with group actions: let $E$ be a subalgebra of $\mathcal{C}^\infty(V)$ such that $E\cap\mathbb{R}[V]$ is finitely generated, under what condition on $E$ do the generators of $E\cap\mathbb{R}[V]$ smoothly generate $E$ ? Schwarz theorem shows this is true for $E=\mathcal{C}^\infty(V)^G$ where $G$ is a compact Lie group acting on $V$ (there are actually counterexamples when $G$ is non compact).

I'm a little confused. If $f\in E^G$ it is both smooth and invariant, so by Schwartz/Bierstone it must be of the form $f = g(P_1,\ldots,P_k)$, which is already what you are after. What am I missing?

My notation may be a bit confusing, I changed them, the point is that I want to express a smooth function in E^G in terms of polynomials in E^G.

@ThomasRichard could you please provide at least some of these counterexamples when $G$ is non compact? Do they include, for instance, some pseudo-orthogonal group?

I added a link to the paper on the non compact counter example.

@PedroLauridsenRibeiro Specifically about pseudo-orthogonal groups, see the discussion at this older question. The upshot is that some distinct real orbits, which can be connected through a single complex orbit, cannot be separated by invariant polynomials.

@ThomasRichard Thanks. Interesting, I had no idea that a counter-example to this could be that simple... If non-properness is key to the failure of Schwarz's theorem, that could potentially happen to the fundamental representation of the Lorentz group, as the isotropy group of a nonzero lightlike vector is non-compact and hence this action is non-proper.

@IgorKhavkine The counter-example presented in the answer to your question concerns the lift of the fundamental representation of the (special) Lorentz group to the space of symmetric contravariant 2-tensors, but your question is about whether closed orbits of the representation can be separated by invariant polynomials. I'm missing the connection (due to my own ignorance, sorry) of that with the failure of Schwarz's theorem. Do invariant smooth functions necessarily separate closed orbits even if the group is non-compact? If so, then I can see why Schwarz's theorem must fail in that case.

@PedroLauridsenRibeiro I don't know if the OP cares to see this discussion under the question here :), so without going into details, because of explicit examples, invariant smooth functions can separate strictly more orbits than polynomials. So some combination of hypotheses in Schwarz's theorem is obviously necessary.
